# Convert SQL Server Table-Valued parameter to C# data access wrapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, codesmith

Using Codesmith 7, I'm trying to generate a C# data access wrapper. The table-valued parameters only show up as `object` in DataType and SystemType.

It boils down to two issues:

1. Is there a way of accessing the user defined table type through Codesmith?
   (so that I can generate a C# datatable with columns prefilled)
2. Is there a way of ascertaining that the parameter is a user defined table type, and so I can set the public/private properties to DataTable instead of object?

Answer (score 0):

I work for CodeSmith....

1. Yes, this should be available. You can access this via the ExtendedProperties object (https://codesmith.atlassian.net/wiki/display/Generator/Using+Extended+Properties). If you take a look, we will put all the information available in the extended properties around custom types.
2. Yes, via extended properties.